# How to remove everything inside parentheses only when it is not a number?

Tags: r

I have a column called 'Player' in a data frame 'players'. The type is 'factor'.
It has values like:
1. Afsar Zazai (AFG),
2. Jubair Hossain (BDESH),
3. Salman Farooq (UAE),
4. Soumya Sarkar (BDESH),
5. Mohammad Nawaz (3) (PAK),
6. Taijul Islam (BDESH)

How can I remove everything inside parentheses, but only when it is not a number. So, the column should look like this after cleansing:
1. Afsar Zazai,
2. Jubair Hossain,
3. Salman Farooq,
4. Soumya Sarkar,
5. Mohammad Nawaz (3),
6. Taijul Islam

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example we can copy/paste into our R session and what the desired output is. Also, what have you tried? Regular expressions are the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
sub("(.*)\\([^0-9]+\\)", "\\1", str1)
```

Comment: Another option would be `"(^.*)\\([[:upper:]]+\\)"` or `"(^.*)\\([[:alpha:]]+\\)"` to catch only upper case or letters.

Answer (score 1):

Akrun's approach is along the lines of creating two groups and extracting the first one. The following approach replaces the found string. Removing white spaces at the end of the string is done using `trimws` function.

```
x <- c("Afsar Zazai (AFG)", "Jubair Hossain (BDESH)", "Salman Farooq (UAE)", "Soumya Sarkar (BDESH)",
       "Mohammad Nawaz (3) (PAK)", "Taijul Islam (BDESH)")

trimws(gsub("\\([[:upper:]]+\\)", "", x))

[1] "Afsar Zazai"        "Jubair Hossain"     "Salman Farooq"     
[4] "Soumya Sarkar"      "Mohammad Nawaz (3)" "Taijul Islam"
```